# -bash: ls: command not found on macOS Big Sur 11.0.1

Tags: bash, ls, path-variables, macos-big-sur

Did I touch something wrong on the terminal?

I'll tell you the details.

```
git clone https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv
cd ~/.rbenv && src/configure && make -C src
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/shims:~/.rbenv/bin"
```

And from here, the 'ls' didn't work in Bash.

Can I know the solution to the problem?

Please! I'm panicking.

I entered the command below because I was embarrassed, but I hope it will be a reference...

```
cd sws
cd ..
ls
cd ..
ls
cd ..
pwd
ls
pwd
cd home
ls
pwd
cd sws
cd user
ls
ls -al
cd ..
pwd
cd ..
ls
pwd
cd ~/.rbenv && src/configure && make -C src
ls
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
ls
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:~/.rbenv/bin"' >> ~/.bash_profile
ls
```

What I've been following:

https://ernestojeh.com/fix-jekyll-on-macos-big-sur

https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#basic-github-checkout

Comment: You need to remove that last line you added to your .bash_profile (`export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:~/.rbenv/bin"`), since it replaces the `PATH` (discarding all previous contents) rather than adding to it. I recommend using an interactive editor, so you can see what you're doing. Oh, and backing up your .bash_profile first, just in case anything else goes wrong. You can get back basic commands in your interactive session with `PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:$PATH"`

Comment: @GordonDavisson wow.. It works! Thank you, I'll take your advice!